# CALayer not displaying correct color

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, colors, calayer

My CALayers are not displaying the correct colors. The project is running on osX 10.8.2 with all XCode updates installed.

Im creating colors in the following way:

```
          lineColor1=CGColorCreateGenericRGB(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
          rootLayer.backgroundColor=lineColor1;
```

All grayscale colors are correct. But when i try making a green color, it has a blue component.

```
          lineColor2=CGColorCreateGenericRGB(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

The upper line will produce the following rgb-color when checked in Photoshop:

```
          (0.0f, 0.98f, 0.29f, 1.0f)
```

The same happens to red and blue. All actual colors are mixed, producing wrong results. Am i missing something? I even used CALayerEssentials, which is provided by Apple, to check if its just my code. The results are the same.

Can anyone help me to find the error here?

Answer (score -1):

In fact your colors are probably more correct than you would assume. CGColorCreateGenericRGB lets you create generic RGB colours.

So what you have done is tell the color system that you want green. Pure green in fact. Now the color system is asked to draw your CALayer on a particular device - probably on your screen.

Your screen has it's own way of displaying color and it is probably off the ideal in all kinds of interesting ways. So the color system takes the color you have asked it to draw theoretically and calculates what the *actual* color values are it needs to draw the CALayer in to make sure it *looks* like what you have asked it to draw.

An easier way to understand is that if you would print this drawing you have made, the color system would have to convert the color to a completely different color space again - this of your printer which probably is CMYK. It's doing exactly the same thing with your screen.

If you want to experience how "non generic" your monitor is, go to "System Preferences", "Displays" and look on the "Color" tab. There are plenty of profiles there you can set to make the appearance of that same "green" change on your monitor...

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer. I have quite a good concept of color and i am not new to this. So i dont think its a color calibtration thing. The CALayers are not diplayed right. The color is far off. If i create a quad in openGL with the same, lets say green, color, it looks just the way it should look. So there must the something wrong with the CALayers. The monitor is displaying the colors in the right way. Im using photoshop on there too. So i dont think its a color correction issue. But thanks anyway.